# Symbolic simplification in Octave seems very basic

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

I'm attempting some symbolic computations in Octave using the symbolic package but I seem to be running aground with issues when it comes to simplification (why I want to use it). For example it works for simple expressions but for more complex matrix operations, it seems to be fail. What is going wrong here:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms a b d t
A = cos(t/2)*exp(i*(a - b/2 - d/2))
B = -sin(t/2)*exp(i*(a-b/2+d/2))
C = sin(t/2)*exp(i*(a + b/2 - d/2))
D = cos(t/2)*exp(i*(a+b/2+d/2))
U = [A, B; C, D]
simplify(expand(conj(U.')*U))
```

I have tried using just simplify without expand. However I should be getting the itentity matrix but instead get an expression - correct but not simplified. Is there a way I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Matlab, symbolic variables are assumed to be complex by default. It looks like you may require that `a`, `b`, `d`, and `t` be real. If so, you need to define them as such so your expressions can be simplified as you expect:

```
syms a b d t real
```

Then the result (at least in Matlab R2017a) from `simplify` will be a symbolic identity matrix.

See the documentation for `syms` and/or `sym` for more. You may also wish to read more about assumptions for symbolic variables: [`sym/assumptions`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/assumptions.html) and [`sym/assume`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/assume.html).